# Deserialize a complex json object + Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I have a class as below

```
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Person> Persons;
```

and I have a simple Rest request as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createEntity(@RequestBody Entity entity)
```

There is a problem when I want to deserialize this object:

> Could not read JSON document: Can not construct instance of
>   com.example.demo.dto.Person: no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from.

The main idea that I dont want use static inner class.

Comment: Please copy/paste the incoming JSON request into your question (i.e. verify that it is actually JSON and not XML)

Comment: You'll need to post your `Person` class. Note that directly serializing JPA entities with relationships is dangerous territory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Person class (preferably a high level class rather than an inner class)
2. either don't add any constructers or add default constructer.